# How to specify insertion point in a word document in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-word

I am building an application to edit an existing word document.

The code should delete a paragraph on the second page and substitute it with another one that is identified by a string variable "Direct_introduction".

The problem is that the text gets inserted at the end of the document and I was not able to insert it anywhere else even after specifying the number of paragraph.

```
If DirectRB.Checked Then
        'introRange.Delete()
        'Dim ODirect_intropara As Word.Paragraph = oDoc.Paragraphs.Add()
        'ODirect_intropara.Range.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
        'ODirect_intropara.Range.Font.Bold = CInt(False)
        'ODirect_intropara.Range.Font.Size = 11
        'ODirect_intropara.Format.SpaceAfter = 0
        'ODirect_intropara.Range.Text = Direct_introduction
        'ODirect_intropara.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
        'ODirect_intropara.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

        introPara = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
        introPara.Range.Text = Direct_introduction
        introPara.Range.Font.Bold = True
        introPara.Format.SpaceAfter = 24    '24 pt spacing after 
paragraph.
        introPara.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
        Rng = oDoc.Range(oDoc.Range.Characters.Count - 1, 
oDoc.Range.Characters.Count)
        Rng.InsertAfter(vbCrLf & "More text inserted using the range 
object")


    ElseIf PartnerRB.Checked Then
        MessageBox.Show("you checked Partner")

    End If
```

Comment: I see nothing in the code provided that does anything other than insert at the end of the document. You also don't mention "the number of the paragraph", which makes it difficult to know what you want. Do you have any control over the creation of document that's being edited? Is there a template for it? Can you modify the template?

Comment: No template. I am not sure how will the insertion work. It should be the first paragraph. Even when I specified Paragraph(1) it did not work.

Comment: Do you know how to use F1? It never ceases to amze me how many folk who post on SO fail to read the documentation before posting.  REad this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphs.add?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm156762117)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute a Find for "Direct_introduction" and, if Found, insert at the current location. For example (in VBA):

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Direct_introduction"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then
    .Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa." & vbCr & _
      "Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna." & vbCr & _
      " Nunc viverra imperdiet enim." & vbCr & _
      "Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus."
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it is a great way to solve the problem. However there is a limitation of 255 chars to find and replace. So I created 6 strings to cover the paragraph. But I need to insert 9 String variables and when I put the InsertParagraphAfter() function it always add the end of the document even after the find function.

Comment: You're evidently approaching this the wrong way. I didn't say to use Replace for the insertion. Moreover, I said to insert at the *current* location (i.e. the location returned by the Find) - not at the end of the document.

Comment: Thanks a million it worked.
I also found another way which is :

With oDoc.Bookmarks.Add("BMname_Introduction").Range.Text = "Introduction_Text"
End With

oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks("introduction").Range)
oPara1.Range.Text = "New Text added at bookmark location"

Comment: Adding a bookmark is entirely unnecessary; all that achieves is bloated code.